# Install Deap for Python (Spyder)

Tags: python, installation, pip, spyder, deap

How should I install deap package for python from spyder?

I have tried:

`pip install deal`

```
import deap
deap.download()
```

Comment: You tried these steps and...?

Comment: What exactly go wrong when you try the steps you mentioned ?

Comment: You install **`deal`** and import **`deap`**... Maybe if you tried to install **`deap`**?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming deap is not installed, type:

```
pip install deap
```

If you get the response

```
Collecting deap
Installing collected packages: deap
Successfully installed deap-1.0.2
```

Then you have just installed deap and you are ready to `import` it into your projects.

If you get the response, `Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): deap in ./Path/To/site-packages`, deap is already installed and you are ready to `import` it.