# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deap' in Spyder3

Tags: spyder, deap

I've got this same error on both Windows 10 and Raspbian.  I checked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36830338/instal-deap-for-python-spyder) but doesn't help me. "pip install deap" downloads fine, but when I execute a DEAP sample code, I get the Module Not Found Error.

Comment: There seem to be 3 packages related to deap.  Deap, sklearn-deap, and sklearn-deap2. I suppose you just need deap?

Comment: I think I just need deap.  Here is the last few lines of the Spyder Console:

File "//raspberrypi/NateFiles/Documents/Computer Science/Scripts/Python3/DEAP-GA.py", line 16, in <module>
    from deap import base

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'deap'

Comment: I found "a solution".  I went to IPython/Jupyter, typed in "!pip install deap".  I no longer get "ModuleNotFoundError".

But, as I hope you noticed this "solution" isn't quite done.  At least, not for this module it seems.  I get a new error.

C:\Users\<user>\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\deap\tools\_hypervolume\pyhv.py:33: ImportWarning: Falling back to the python version of hypervolume module. Expect this to be very slow.
  "module. Expect this to be very slow.", ImportWarning)

Comment: A work-around I found was to put the DEAP script I wrote into the deap folder itself, so the module resources are local.  Not an ideal fix, but at least it's working.

Answer (score 0):

From [here](https://deap.readthedocs.io/en/master/installation.html), running "easy_install deap" command worked for me.